# How to fix Drupal 9 Base url issue while using load balancer

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

since the base URL config is deprecated and our Drupal 9 Site is using load balancer we are facing issue setting up the base URL .

instead of base URL its displaying the load balancer IP ,

any help regarding the same is appreciated

Referred the following suggestion from drupal.org and blogs
and made the following changes

```
$settings['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;
$settings['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$settings['reverse_proxy_host_header'] = 'X-ORIGINAL-HOST';

$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [
  '^d9\.johndoe\.dev$',
  '^10\.101\.9\.23$',
];
```

this worked for D8 setup but not foe the D9 setup

links referred as of now

- https://www.drupal.org/node/425990
- https://www.drupal.org/node/3030558
- https://www.drupal.org/project/trusted_reverse_proxy
- https://www.drupal.org/project/reverse_proxy_header
- https://www.58bits.com/blog/2021/02/18/canonical-urls-https-and-drupal-89-reverse-proxy-settings
- https://medium.com/@lmakarov/drupal-8-and-reverse-proxies-the-base-url-drama-c5553cbc9a3e